# How can I expose my ASP.NET Core web api to be used without http?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know this sound strange, but please bear with me. We have a legacy desktop app (DataFlex), and we are developing a new web app. Both apps share the same business logic. We are in the process of moving the business logic to a centralized project that is exposed as an asp.net-core web api, to be used both by the desktop app and the web app.

So far, we have been able to access the new business logic project from the legacy desktop app via COM, but because maintaining interfaces and DataFlex wrapper classes is a pain, we are hoping to find an easier way.

We could access the business logic using the web api via http. But many users are still only using the desktop app, and setting up web servers for all of them is not something that can be done anytime soon. So we want to call the asp.net-core project in a way that resembles the way a web app does it, passing method calls as strings (JSON?)

Is this feasible? If so, how?

Comment: The proper solution would be to simply call the web APIs from within your desktop application over HTTP. – But no, you cannot use ASP.NET Core without HTTP. HTTP is the protocol that it is all about.